# Truncate file in ocaml

Tags: file, ocaml, truncate

How to truncate file to size N in ocaml ?

I don't see a function in Pervasive. The closest thing is "open_trunc" flag which I'm not really sure what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're under Unix, you can use

```
val Unix.truncate : string -> int -> unit
```

It "runcates the named file to the given size".
But this function is not implemented in the Windows version of OCaml (or more precisely, it is not emulated).

If you're under Windows and want to emulate it, you might be interested in

```
val really_input : in_channel -> string -> int -> int -> unit
```

"`really_input ic buf pos len` reads `len` characters from channel `ic`, storing them in string `buf`, starting at character number `pos`. Raise `End_of_file` if the end of file is reached before `len` characters have been read. Raise `Invalid_argument "really_input"` if `pos` and `len` do not designate a valid substring of `buf`."

Answer (score 2):

I think you are correct.
**open_trunc** -Open the named file for writing, and return a new output channel on that file, positionned at the beginning of the file. The file is truncated to zero length if it already exists. It is created if it does not already exists. Raise **Sys_error** if the file could not be opened.

Refer this link [also](http://www.ocaml-lang.org/tutorials/file_manipulation.html).

Answer (score 2):

The OS capabilities of Pervasives correspond roughly to what you can do in standard C. There is no function to truncate a file to a specified length in standard C, all you can do is truncate a file to be empty when you open it (exposed through the `Open_trunc` flag). There is one in Unix/POSIX ([`truncate`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/truncate.html)), so look for it in the [`Unix` module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/libref/Unix.html), which does have a [`truncate`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/libref/Unix.html#VALtruncate) function (or [`ftruncate`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/libref/Unix.html#VALftruncate) for an open file, again following [Unix/POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ftruncate.html)).